# Prime testing algorithm not working properly

Tags: c++, algorithm, testing, primes

I have a prime testing algorithm, which I got from Project Euler, but it returns *false* when 43 is passed as input. The pseudo code was given in the overview, which I converted into c++ code. I may have made a mistake in converting the pseudo code. What is the actual problem with the algorithm?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

bool is_prime(int n)
{
    if(n <= 1)
    {
         return false;
    }
    else if(n < 4)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if(n % 2 == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if(n < 9)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if(n % 3 == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        int r = sqrt(n);
        int f = 5;
        while(f <= r)
        {
            if(n % f == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            if((n + 2) % f == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            f = f + 6;
        }
       return true;
    }
}

int main()
{
    cout << is_prime(43);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A lot of brackets and redundand `else`s make your code unreadable

Comment: Debug it with value 43. Than you will see what goes wrong. If you do not like depuggers, use printf-debugging.

Comment: Your second test in the loop is `(43 + 2) % 5 == 0`, which is obviously true.

Comment: edit it to remove redundant conditions

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm is right but here is following mistake

```
       if((n + 2) % f == 0)  //wrong
        {

            return false;
        }
```

should be

```
      if(n%(f+2) == 0)  //Right
        {

            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an algorithm error. Instead of 
`(n+2)%f`
 it should read 
`n%(f+2)`

Answer (score 0):

Others have pointed out your error.  You can simplify your code somewhat, reducing all those `if` statements:

```
bool is_prime(int n)
{
  if(n <= 1)
  {
     return false;
  }

  if(n % 2 == 0)
  {
    return n == 2;
  }

  if(n % 3 == 0)
  {
    return n == 3;
  }

  // Check for factors of 5, 7, ...
```